# How can I create a singleton in Guice that uses a constructor with a flag?

Tags: guice

So I hava a mapper class:

```
public class TmaticMapper implements Mapper {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TmaticMapper.class);
private MapperFactory mf = null;
private MapperFacade mapperFacade = null;
private Map<String, List<String>> toDoList = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

public TmaticMapper(Configuration propKey) {
    super();
    this.mf = this.buildMapperFactory(propKey.toString());
    this.mapperFacade = mf.getMapperFacade();
}
```

That I need to use as a singleton.  The class is constructed two ways but I need only one of each (and I really do want to make just one.  It is doing things like changing byte code and I only want it to do its thing once per jvm).  I have tried "@Singleton" and such but I don't see any difference at startup.

I use this instantiate:

```
binder.bind(Mapper.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("RecordToDto")).toInstance(new TmaticMapper(Mapper.Configuration.recordToDto));
```

and inject this way:

```
@Inject
    @Named("RecordToDto")
    private Mapper tMapper;
```

How do I instantiate only one of these at startup and inject it?

Answer (score 0):

try creating a provider with `@Provides` rather than using the binding syntax in the module `config()` method.  That will allow you to add some logic to the singleton returned from the provider.

Example Module:

```
public class YourModule extends AbstractModule {

  private Config config

  public YourModule(Config config) {
    this.config = config;
  }

  @Override 
  protected void configure() {/*prefer providers*/}

  @Provides
  @Singleton 
  public TmaticMapper providesTmaticMapper(Config config) {
    if (myflag) {
      return new TmaticMapper(config);
    }
    else {
      return new TmaticMapper(config);
    }
  }
}
```

Create your injector:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new YourModule(config));
```

Get instance of your singleton:

```
TmaticMapper mapper = injector.getInstance(TmaticMapper.class);
```

Every time you call `getInstance()` on that injector you will receive the same  instance of `TmaticMapper`.  If you create another injector you will get a new instance which will be scoped to that injector.

Comment: Each time it is hit?  I need this mapper in multiple instances of other classes...

Comment: are you instantiating multiple injectors?

Comment: GAA.  I am sorry, I don't now much about Guice.  No, not multiple injectors.  So I just put this in my Module class.  What is the "Config" above?  And how do I inject it in my class?

Comment: `Config` is just a place holder for a class that holds your config.  its internals are completely up to you.  I've extended the example above to illustrate the module and its usage.  This is also a good place to get info about Guice https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118331/discussion-between-ben-glasser-and-markthegrea).